# jQuery plugin issues in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't understand why my code doesn't work on internet explorer/
This is my index.php where I am invoking js libraries.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/shadowbox.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slides.min.jquery.js" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.simpleWeather-2.0.1.min.js" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.clock.js" > </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/default.js" > </script>
```

And this is my default.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Shadowbox.init({
        overlayOpacity: 0.8
    }, setupDemos);

    if (typeof $().slides != "undefined") {
        $('#slides').slides({
            preload: true,
            preloadImage: 'images/slides/loading.gif',
            play: 3000,
            pause: 2500,
            hoverPause: true,
            animationStart: function(current){
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:-35
                },100);
            },
            animationComplete: function(current){
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:0
                },200);
            },
            slidesLoaded: function() {
                $('.caption').animate({
                    bottom:0
                },200);
            }
        });
    }

    $.each($(".menu li"), function(index, li) {
        if ($(li).hasClass("active")) {
            $("title").append(": " + $(li).children("a").text());
        }
    });

    if (typeof $.simpleWeather != "undefined") {
        $.simpleWeather({
            location: 'Armenia, Yerevan',
            unit: 'c',
            success: function(weather) {
                html = "<div style='height: 117px;'><h2>"+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</h2>';
                html += '<img style="float:left;" width="125px" src="'+weather.image+'">';
                html += '<p>'+weather.temp+'&deg; '+weather.units.temp+'<br /></p>';
                html += '</div>';

                $("#weather").html(html);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
            }
        });
    }

    $('#yerevan-time').clock({offset: '+4', type: 'analog'});
    $('#london-time').clock({offset: '+0', type: 'analog'});
    $('#new-york-time').clock({offset: '-5', type: 'analog'});
});

function setupDemos() {
    Shadowbox.setup("a[rel=photos]", {
        gallery:        "cars",
        continuous:     true,
        counterType:    "skip"
    });
}


$(function() {
    $( "#day1" ).datepicker();
    $( "#day2").datepicker();
    });
```

I can't find a solution here. You can check this out [here](http://artourbus.am/ARTourBus/). This is my website. So in internet explorer the clock and the weather doesn't work. What's the problem here. Any help will be useful. thanks.

Comment: add $.noConflict(); to ready function as a first statement.

Comment: Any specific IE version? Which ones have you tested in?

Answer (score 1):

The error has nothing to do with the code you posted..

If you check the console, you will see an error that is related to google maps.

And that error is being fired when you run the `initialize` method (*you have it bound to the `onload` event of the `body` tag*)

Remove that to check that the clocks work correctly, and then make sure to run in only when there are maps to be shown in the page..

---

**Update**

The other , more important, issue in your case is that the clock plugin you use has code like this

```
jQuery(_this)
    .find(".sec")
    .css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate});
```

Seeing the vendor prefixes `-moz-` and `-webkit-` means that the rotation of the hands is only applied to the mozilla and webkit browsers..

They have specifically excluded all other browsers..

---

***Modern IE (>=9) workaround***

For IE >= 9 you could add `"-ms-transform" : srotate`

```
jQuery(_this)
        .find(".sec")
        .css({"-moz-transform" : srotate, "-webkit-transform" : srotate, "-ms-transform" : srotate});
```

and it would work (*as IE >= 9 supports rotation..*)

(*make sure to correct the code for all hands.. my example is only about the **seconds***)

Comment: @fish40, updated answer. Clock plugin seems to be made only for Mozilla and Webkit browsers..

Comment: And what should I do for ie, whould should i add here, if it possible?

Comment: this doesn't work even in IE9, tryed this solution but for IE no way

Comment: @shershen, what does not work ? `srotate` should have a string value like `'rotate(50deg)'`, and it seems to be working just fine at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/7ZJYr/ ..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli the clock jquery plugin (http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Clock/), in IE 9 - screen - http://i48.tinypic.com/o5fn.png, not your fancy fiddle

Comment: @shershen, that is because that example page is using jQuery 1.2.6 If you use a more recent one it works just fine.. Try in the console of that page to run `jQuery.noConflict().getScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js',function(){$("#min").css('-ms-transform','rotate(50deg)')})` and it will work.. ***btw*** that is not my page nor plugin ...

Comment: @shershen and here is the full example from the site you posted working .. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/5SxAX/